# How to disable the remaining input field depend upon the value entered in the textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three input fields and all the fields are enabled. Now When the user enters the text in any field then rest of the field should disable.

For example, The user enter in the name field the `emp_id` and `temp_id` field `disabled` or if enter in `emp_id` field then disable name and temp_id, or if enter `temp_id` the disable name and `emp_id` text field.

I am confused to use the logic in `if-else` the condition. Would you help me out in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('.disabled_field').on('keyup',function(){ 
    if($(this).val().length >0){
     // $("").prop('disabled','disabled');
    }else{
       // $("").removeProp('disabled','disabled');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="disable_field" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" name="emp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="emp_id">
<input type="text" name="temp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="temp_id">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `input` event is better fit for this situation. Change the property based on the length of the value of the control. Simply use not[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to disable all the inputs. 
Try following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.disable_field').on('input',function(){
    if($(this).val().length) // Checks if there is any value present or not
     $('.disable_field').not(this).prop('disabled', true); // Disable all input except the current.
    else
     $('.disable_field').removeAttr('disabled'); // Enable all input by removing the "disabled" property from controls.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="disable_field" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" name="emp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="emp_id">
<input type="text" name="temp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="temp_id">
```

Comment: Good point for `not(this)`, but your method does not re-enable inputs on blur.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<input type="text" name="name" class="disable_field" placeholder="name">
 <input type="text" name="emp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="emp_id">
 <input type="text" name="temp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="temp_id">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('input.disable_field').keyup(function(){ 
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $('input.disable_field').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('input.disable_field').prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            }  
 });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inputs = $('.disable_field');
  inputs.on('keyup', function() {

    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      inputs.filter((i, f) => f !== this).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      inputs.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="name" class="disable_field" placeholder="name">
 <input type="text" name="emp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="emp_id">
 <input type="text" name="temp_id" class="disable_field" placeholder="temp_id">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```